# Why are Dropdowns in Bootstrap 3 giving unusual characters?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting some strange artefacts appearing inside Bootstrap dropdowns and collapsable panels. Here's an example:

[image: Weird BS character]

If you notice over the "t" there appears a little ">". When these appear in a drop down, they will change direction depending on whether you are expanding or contracting the dropdown.

When I look at the code, there is nothing there:

Dropdown code:

```
 <a data-toggle="dropdown">Project Quote<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Collapsable panel code:

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"
                       aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Customer Details
 </a>
```

As I recently changed the css Boostrap to 3.3.7 I changed it back to 3.2 and sure enough, the strange character changed shape into a little arrow, although it did not disappear.

Lastly, I tried removing the class "caret". This had no effect.

Any ideas how to get rid of these things, or is it a bug of sorts?

Comment: I believe that's a caret. `<span class="caret"></span>` Have you tried removing this whole span?

Comment: Just to be sure, hard-refresh the page so there's no conflict between versions. Ctrl+F5 (win) or Cmd+F5 (mac).

Comment: I also believe the same. It is because of `<span class="caret"></span>`. Try removing or style it according to your requirement.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

They're neither *"strange artefacts"*, nor *"unusual characters"*. They are called carets and they increase the user experience of the website you're creating, by letting users know that "button" is a dropdown.

Statistically speaking, if you do not add a caret to a dropdown, a large chunk of users will not open the dropdown, because they will think it's a button and they will navigate away from current page if they press it.

To hide the caret in Bootstrap 3.3.7, use:

```
.dropdown .caret { display: none; }
```

If the above code doesn't hide the caret, you might be using a custom theme and you need to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I could inspect the issue and provide you with the proper CSS for your case.

A better alternative would be to increase the right padding of your dropdowns, making sure the caret does not overlap with content:

```
.dropdown { padding-right: 3rem; }
```

You might also consider decreasing the `right` value of the caret itself, so it's rendered closer to the right-margin of the button.

Comment: Thanks!! Problem solved. It had nothing to do with the caret. I had previously imported a Bootstrap dashboard from bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

This dashboard made use of the following css which I identified as being the source of my problem. When I removed the CSS, problem solved. Many thanks !! 

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}

Comment: So it was a custom theme, replicating carets without using carets, but pseudo elements. Glad you sorted it out.